# Expected value of a squared fraction of Y

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

I need to work out the following:

$$
E[(\frac {Y(x+h)-Y(x)}h)^2]
$$

I've already worked out the below and am supposed to use it to work out the above.

$$E[(Y(x+h)-Y(x))^2]$$

I'm not able to find any information about expected value rules that covers this. I think that if it was of the form $E(\frac Xa)$ I could just rearrange it as $\frac 1a E(X)$ but I doubt it is going to be that simple.

Comment: The argument in the first expression is $1/h^2=1/a$ times the argument in the second expression. If $h$ were a constant, then your final remark would apply, so evidently $h$ is supposed to be a random variable, right?  What do you know about it?

Comment: To basically say the same thing as whuber, but coming from the other end, if $h$ isn't random, you just employ exactly the argument in your last sentence ($X= ({Y(x+h)-Y(x)})^2$ and $a=h^2$) - in which case I invite you to answer your own question down in the answer space. [If $h$ is random, you need to deal with that random variable and its relationship to other variables, in which case anything you know about $h$ might help.]

Comment: h is a constant, so does that mean it's as easy as just taking out $1/h^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $h \not=0$ is a constant we get
$$
   E[(\frac {Y(x+h)-Y(x)}h)^2] = (1/h^2) E[(Y(x+h)-Y(x))^2] \\
   = (1/h^2) E [Y^2(x+h) - 2 Y(x+h)Y(x) + Y^2(x)]
$$
but to continue we really needs to know more about the joint distribution of $Y(x), Y(x+h)$, information you have not given.

Comment: Thank you for trying to close this open thread.  (1) You lost a square in the middle.  (2) In many (if not most) applications, direct information is available about the moments of the increments $Y(x+h)-Y(x),$ so it would be a step back to expand its square.  It's therefore probably better and clearer to leave it unexpanded.